# Responsive behaviour in react native with styled-components

Tags: react-native, media-queries, styled-components

I have been trying to find a way of having responsive sizes and of adding/removing content from the screen depending on the size.
In react-native media queries do not exist, neither em/rem for sizes, anyone can share their experience by implementing layouts that for example:

- In a small screen show one button, but in an table 3 buttons?
- on a small screen the font-size is 16 but in the table should be 24

Comment: Welcome to SO! Cal you show us what did you try so we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

welcome to SO. for responsiveness, ive been using this library [RN-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen) , which is very easy .SUppose youhave a component with `height:100 and width:200 ,` and your screen size is 360*640. so you need to replace height and width by

```
height:hp("15.6%") // 100/640 = 15.6
width:wp("55.5%") //200/360 = 55.5
```

Otherwise if you dont want to use any library you can use the Dimensions of React native.

```
import {DImensions} from react native;
const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
```

and after that use height like

```
height:0.156*deviceHeight 
width:0.55*deviceWidth
```

hope it helps

Comment: I did came across that and another packages that solve one of the issues(sizes), but not the part of adding/removing elements from the screen, still thanks for your input